# Overriding http.Server.Serve

Tags: go

I need to embed the default `http.Server` in my own server struct and customize the `Serve` method.

The server needs to short circuit the `go c.serve()` call and only run that line if it has the computing resources available to respond within 50ms. Otherwise the server is just going to send a 204 and move on.

This is *almost* straightforward.

```
type PragmaticServer struct {
    http.Server
    Addr    string
    Handler http.Handler
}

func (srv *PragmaticServer) Serve(l net.Listener) error {
    defer l.Close()
    var tempDelay time.Duration // how long to sleep on accept failure
    for {
        // SNIP for clarity
        c, err := srv.newConn(rw)
        if err != nil {
            continue
        }
        c.setState(c.rwc, StateNew) // before Serve can return
        go c.serve()
    }
}
```

So, again. This almost works. Except that `srv.newConn` is an unexported method, as is `c.serve` and `c.setState`, which means that I end up having to copy and paste pretty much the entirety of `net/http` in order for this to compile. Which is basically a fork. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to do that without reimplementing most of the Server code. Short of that, we usually intercept the call either just before at `conn.Accept`, or just after at `Handler.ServerHTTP`.

The first method is to create a custom `net.Listener` that filters out connections before they are even handed off to the `http.Server`. While this can respond faster, and consume fewer resources, it however makes it less convenient to write http responses, and precludes you from limiting requests on already open connections.

The second way to handle this, is to just wrap the handlers and intercept the request before any real work has been done. You most likely want to create a `http.Handler` to filter the requests, and pass them through to your main handler. This can also be more flexible, since you can filter based on the route, or other request information if you so choose.

Comment: Thanks Jim, after properly reading through the code for `c.serve` I realised that doing it at this level wouldn't be useful anyway, because the traffic is all coming from one endpoint (RTB Exchange) and the requests I really wanted to filter were arriving after this inside the go routines.